# zend framework2 installation

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to installing the library of the zend framework2.I have downloaded the skeleton application of zend framework2 and run the command in command prompt as in the zend framework installation guide on zend site but i am getting an error[image]

it shows me an error **could not open input file composer.phar**

I checked the library which i have downloaded from git there is no composer.phar.There is only composer.json and a lock file of composer.I google out about this problem and find that it  is due to open_ssl exention is disable in php.ini file.I checked the php.ini and found enabled.I am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Regards to the official documentation for the skeleton application here
[Github documentation](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication) it says

> The easiest way to create a new ZF2 project is to use Composer. If you don't have it already installed, then please install as per the documentation.

with the documentation here
[Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

And the [Composer website here](https://getcomposer.org/)

Plus, from your screen behind your cmd line we can see this line taken from the website you show :

> ZendSkeletonApplication is set up to use Composer (http://getcomposer.org) to resolve its dependencies. In this case, the dependency is Zend Framework 2 itself.

Composer is a soft his name is called composer.phar. It is what your looking for

Comment: Thanx for reply Hooli.

Comment: Accept this as the correct answer if it's correct, your welcome.

Answer (score -1):

go to C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin using command prompt then run composer cammands

Comment: You realize this does not make any sense?